# Hibernate shows error, class is not mapped

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have created a DAO class, entity and all Hibernate configurations, but Hibernate keeps showing the same error:

> QuerySyntaxException: StudentEntity is not mapped [SELECT s FROM StudentEntity s]

Where is my mistake?

Table Script

```
CREATE TABLE student(
  id int(3) NOT NULL,
  firstName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  age int(2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO student VALUES ('101','yashik','23');

SELECT * FROM student;
```

Entity Class

```
package com.demo.entity;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class StudentEntity {
  @Id
  private int id;
  private String firstName;
  private int age;
  //getter and setter
```

DAO Class

```
package com.demo.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import com.demo.entity.StudentEntity;
import com.demo.resources.HibernateUtility;
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {
  @Override
  public StudentEntity getStudent(Integer studentID) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
    Session s1=null;
    StudentEntity stu=null;
    s1=sessionFactory.openSession();
    s1.beginTransaction();
    String st1="SELECT s FROM StudentEntity s";
    Query q1=s1.createQuery(st1);
    List<StudentEntity> l1=q1.list();
    stu.setAge(l1.get(0).getAge());
    stu.setId(l1.get(0).getId());
    stu.setFirstName(l1.get(0).getFirstName());
    if (s1 != null) {
        s1.close();
    }
    return stu;
  }
}
```

Hibernate Utility

```
package com.demo.resources;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtility {

    private static final String CONFIGURATION_LOCATION="com/demo/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory=getSessionFactory();

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            // loads configuration and mappings
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(CONFIGURATION_LOCATION);
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            // builds a session factory from the service registry
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory(){
        return getSessionFactory();
    }
    public static void closeSessionFactory(){
        if(!sessionFactory.isClosed()){
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rmc</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">******</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <mapping class="com.demo.entity.StudentEntity"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

error message

```
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:18 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.0.Final}
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:18 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:18 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:19 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rmc]
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Wed Jul 06 22:06:19 IST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:19 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jul 06, 2016 10:06:19 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: StudentEntity is not mapped [SELECT s FROM StudentEntity s]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:633)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:101)
    at com.demo.dao.StudentDAOImpl.getStudent(StudentDAOImpl.java:22)
    at com.demo.userInterface.UserInterface.main(UserInterface.java:9)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: StudentEntity is not mapped [SELECT s FROM StudentEntity s]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:625)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: StudentEntity is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3704)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3593)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:574)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: can you change String st1="SELECT s FROM StudentEntity s"; to               String st1="FROM StudentEntity";       and try

Comment: not this is not working, it produces the same error. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question a bit to put the focus more on the complete error message, right at the start. So I removed some of your introductory text which does not really help readers to understand your problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

> String st1="SELECT s FROM StudentEntity s";

In this you are trying to get all the data in that entity if I am correct.

I usually use

**String st1="from StudentEntity";**

That is all, tell if that works.